# Include ggplot2 function in package

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, namespaces, r-package

I am trying to include the following ggplot2 helper function in a package [it wraps labels in grid_facet(.~variable, labeller = "plot.label.wrap")]:

```
#' Label wrapper for ggplot
#'
#' Include in the facet_grid option of ggplot.
#' @param variable
#' @param value
#' @return wrapper
#' @export

plot.label.wrap <- function(variable, value) {

  lapply(strwrap(as.character(value), width=15, simplify=FALSE),
         paste, collapse="\n")
}
```

My DESCRIPTION file includes: Imports: ggplot2. The scripts that uses the function includes: library(ggplot2).

The package builds, reloads and gives the documentation upon ?plot.label.wrap. It can be found:

```
> getAnywhere(plot.label.wrap)
A single object matching ‘plot.label.wrap’ was found
It was found in the following places
  registered S3 method for plot from namespace mypackage
  namespace:mypackage
with value

function(variable, value) {

  lapply(strwrap(as.character(value), width=15, simplify=FALSE),
         paste, collapse="\n")
}
<environment: namespace:mypackage>
```

However:

```
> plot.label.wrap
Error: object 'plot.label.wrap' not found
```

So my question is, why is this function found in the namespace of mypackage but not on the command line itself?

Comment: what does the namespace line for this function look like? it seems to be treated as an s3 method when that doesn't look like your intent

Comment: S3method(plot,footprint.facet), but no export line for that function.

Comment: try `#' @export plot.label.wrap`

Comment: By the name of your function, it looks like it's the `plot` method for `label.wrap` objects. Just rename the function to e.g. `plot_label_wrap` and it should work.

Comment: This needs an answer rather than a solution in comments...

Comment: Agree, will answer myself if necessary, but I am not sure if I understand what is going on. All other functions worked without adding the name of the function to @export.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the solution in the comments was to be more specific about the export like below

```
#' Label wrapper for ggplot
#'
#' Include in the facet_grid option of ggplot.
#' @param variable
#' @param value
#' @return wrapper
#' @export plot.label.wrap

plot.label.wrap <- function(variable, value) {

  lapply(strwrap(as.character(value), width=15, simplify=FALSE),
         paste, collapse="\n")
}
```

roxygen tries to be smart about things like the `@usage`, `@details`, and `@exports` to make things simplier, but sometimes, like in this example, it doesn't always work out.

`plot` is an S3 generic method which can be defined as `plot.someclass` which will create a plotting method for some object `x` with `class` "someclass" and can be called simply by `plot(x)`.

roxygen thinks that `someclass` for your package was "label.wrap" and exported `plot.label.wrap` as an S3 method rather than a normal function, expecting you to use it as `plot(x)` where `class(x)` is "label.wrap" and not trying to use `plot.label.wrap` directly as you tried (and found it doesn't work).

Alternatively, like @shadow mentioned, you could avoid this confusion by not using periods in function names, eg `plot_label_wrap`, `plot_label.wrap`,`plot_labelwrap`, etc. You don't *have* to, but in a few rare circumstances, using periods causes unexpected behaviors.